# How to create multi dimentional v-model as name attribute in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hi please i'm looking for a way to replace : **`name="variant[attribute][]"`**  by **`v-model=""`**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="variant[attribute][]" placeholder="Color">
```

i mean create a multi dementional array but with v-model not name attribute

this is my vue.js data code :

```
data () {
  return {
    tags: []
  }
}
```